# How to enumerate a particular char from a long string to identify its index in a string.

Tags: python

I have write down a code given below to enumerate the position of the string and its occurrence:

```
line = "How  to enumerate a particular char from a long string to identify its index in a string."


for i, ch in enumerate(line):
        if ch=='a':
            v = 0
            print v++1,"-->",i+1,
```

output of this code is coming out like this:

```
1 --> 15 1 --> 19 1 --> 22 1 --> 29 1 --> 34 1 --> 42 1 --> 81
```

what changes i should make so that i could get output like this:

```
1 --> 15 2 --> 19 3 --> 22 4 --> 29 5 --> 34 6 --> 42 7 --> 81
```

its showing the index value with the char "a" and its number like how many times it came.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(line):
        if ch == 'a':
            v += 1
            print("%d --> %d"%(v, i+1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> for i, ch in enumerate(line):
    if ch == 'a':
        counter += 1 #The right way to do it, number++ is useless in python,
                     #since this is not a post increment operator :)
        print "%d --> %d"%(counter, i+1) 


1 --> 15
2 --> 19
3 --> 22
4 --> 29
5 --> 34
6 --> 42
7 --> 81
```

Each time the character is matched, you increment the counter, so you have the results!

Comment: More that `++` is useless because it's a syntax error and not a post increment operator is a bit more accurate :)

Comment: Not in a print statement, you'll increment it. But only in that statement.

Comment: Okay... the way it's being used it's binding as v + (+1)` - Just `v++` wouldn't work though... but yeah... I was just saying it wasn't down to mutability which you've fixed anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition can be also done in one line (it even fits in 80 chars limit!):

```
>>> line = 'How  to enumerate a particular char from a long string to identify its index in a string.'
>>> for oc, idx in enumerate((i for i, x in enumerate(line, 1) if x == 'a'), 1):
...    print oc, '-->', idx

1 --> 15
2 --> 19
3 --> 22
4 --> 29
5 --> 34
6 --> 42
7 --> 81
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
line = ("How  to enumerate a particular char from a "
        "long string to identify its index in a string.")

occurrences = 0
for i, ch in enumerate(line, 1):
    if ch=='a':
        occurrences += 1
        print occurrences, "-->", i,
print
```

Output:

```
1 --> 15 2 --> 19 3 --> 22 4 --> 29 5 --> 34 6 --> 42 7 --> 81
```

Note that the index is displayed as you wanted, but technically it not the correct value because indices in Python start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Hello Mr Martineau, note that it's faster to create the string ``'%d --> %d' % (occurrences,i),`` and print it than printing ``occurences``, then printing ``' --> '`` then printing ``i`` : I compared these two ways, the first one is 3 times faster. - See also the solutions in my answer and what I said about their fastest execution times compared to solutions like yours.

Comment: @eyquem: The OP's question wasn't about speed, nor did I claim my solution was the fastest possible way to accomplish the goal. Furthermore I don't think it matters much.

Comment: It does't matter much, you are right. By the way, that's the reason we think that Python is as much convenient as C++, for a lot of applications for which gaining microseconds isn't crucial, isn't it. But I think also it doesn't require a lot of effort to add a heavy improvement. - For the first argument, I would say it's a good pedagogic practice to show more to an OP than what he asked for. Or there wouldn't exist the notion of XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regx = re.compile('a')

line = "How  to enumerate a particular char from "\
       "a long string to identify its index in a string."

print ' '.join('%d --> %d' % ( N , m.start()+1 )
               for N,m in enumerate(regx.finditer(line),1))
```

OR

```
def froo(line, N=1):
    for i in xrange(len(line)):
        if line[i]=='a':
            yield N,i+1
            N += 1

print ' '.join('%d --> %d' % x for x in froo(line))
```

OR ALSO

```
def frenum(line, N=1):
    for i,ch in enumerate(line,1):
        if ch=='a':
            yield N,i
            N += 1

print ' '.join('%d --> %d' % x for x in frenum(line))
```

These three solutions have executions times very very equivalent, I didn't succeed to put in evidence which one is the fastest, with a code of comparison: there is just 1% of difference between their execution times and the one detected as the fastest varies from one execution of comparison to another.

Note that the other solutions that print the occurences one after the other, in the other answers, instead of joining them before to print all them in one printing, are much more slower:
they're 5,5 times slower in an execution in a command line window, and 20 times slower in an execution in an IDLE window.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension it can be written like below. It doesn't pretty print and it uses zero based indices but it puts the answer in a tuple list which probably is useful.

```
line = "How  to enumerate a particular char from a long string to identify its index in a string."

print list(enumerate([x[0] for x in enumerate(line) if x[1]=='a']))
```

or like this if you want the printing and indices based on 1:

```
for y in enumerate([x[0] for x in enumerate(line) if x[1]=='a']):
    print "%d --> %d" % (y[0]+1,y[1]+1)

Output:

1 --> 15
2 --> 19
3 --> 22
4 --> 29
5 --> 34
6 --> 42
7 --> 81
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome on stackoverflow. But you should test your code before posting it.